Running multiple SQL-Statements with Python
im looking to run multiple SQL-Statements with Python. To run one Statement works, but if i want to run Multiple Statements only the first one works:
This is what i tried so far:
# Name of the DB2-Table
table_name = 'Table1'

# SQL-Statement
sql = f"""
    TRUNCATE TABLE {table_name} IMMEDIATE; -- Clear the table
    INSERT INTO {table_name} (Year, UserNr, Username, Age) -- Insert Values
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
"""

The Problem:
Only the first Truncate Statement works. Means the Table will be Empty after running the Script. Is there a way to run both statements?
Edited:
I'm using pyodbc and pandas. DB-Server Platform is linux.

Which interface to Db2 are you using? pyodbc? dbi? ibm_db? pandas? sqlalchemy?,  and what is your Db-server platform (z/os, i-series(as400), linux/unix/windows/cloud) because different platforms allow different functionality.  Please edit your question to add these facts

pyodbc apparently does not support anonymous-blocks (multiple SQL statements inside a BEGIN...END block). Additionally such blocks might not be parameterisable in Db2-LUW.   pyodbc also does not support the callproc API to allow you to call a stored-procedure (i.e. a stored procedure that contains the block of SQL statements you want to run) although the ibm_db interface supports callproc.   You probably need to execute the statements one by one.

In most interfaces, you need to run each statement individually. You can control the semantics by using transaction scopes.

pyodbc doesn't support multiple statement in a single line you have to break your query and execute one-by-one.
